# PHP post method apparently not working

Tags: php, ajax, post

LATEST EDIT: It turns out that, in formprocessing.php, isset($_POST['submit1']) is FALSE (where 'submit1' is now the name of the submit button; originally it did not have a name). As seen in the code below, I did not test for this originally.

It does explain a lot. But the remaining question is *why* isset($_POST['submit1']) is FALSE.

NOTE: This question has been edited to reflect more recent insights.

As a PHP beginner, I’m experimenting with posting forms to the server, and it does not work. In all likelyhood I’m overlooking something simple, but I just don’t see it.

I have two files: ‘form.php’ and ‘formprocessing.php’, both located in the same folder. I have included the full code below, but first some explanation. The file ‘form.php’ contains the form itself, including the ‘post’ method. The file ‘formprocessing.php’ is the destination, so to speak, of the ‘post’ method, i.e. “action = formprocessing.php”.

The idea is that the formprocessing should take place without 'formprocessing.php' loading or 'form.php' reloading (hence "event.preventDefault();" in form.php). I’m aware that I could also be posting to ‘form.php’ itself, but for now I want to go with two separate files.

I’ve taken the code of ‘form.php’ from the jQuery-site almost literally (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  , the last example). I’ve changed the file name in the action attribute to ‘formprocessing.php’, and added a necessary JSON.stringify command (see below).

The rest of the code in ‘formprocessing.php’ simply extracts the value of the posted input field (there is only one field in the form), and gives it back to ‘form.php’ in the form of a JSON-object (which is then stringified in form.php). At least that’s the idea!

The  script generated at 'formprocessing.php.' - after typing, say, "xxx" into the input field - is as follows:

```
<script> {"content":"xxx"} </script>
```

Now to my eyes, this script SEEMS correct -- but is it? That is the first thing I'd like to know for sure now.

EDIT: I've now removed all the HTML tags in formprocessing.php. Which also means that the generated script reduces to {"content":"xxx"} , i.e. only the JSON-object. Doesn't change the result though.

Because something does go wrong later. That is, at the end of ‘form.php’, I attach the contents of the data returned from ‘formprocessing.php’ to a div element. But in fact the string attached to the div turns out to be "{"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"length":9},"selector":"#content"}" -- i.e., indicating an object of length 0. Rather than the actual data supposedly returned from 'formprocessing.php' (which as I said also equal the original input to the form field).

Here comes the code of ‘form.php’:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="formprocessing.php" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>

    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

    /* Put the results in a div */
    posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
    contentstring = JSON.stringify(content);
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( contentstring );

    });

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here’s the code of ‘formprocessing.php’:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Contact</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>   

   <script>

   <?php
   echo "alert('Hello!');";
   $invoer = $_POST['s'];
   echo ( json_encode(array("content" => $invoer)) ); 
   ?>

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I should just have used Javascript there (before the PHP opening tag). As I said, I'm pretty much a beginner.

Comment: Use firebug and see the console whether your ajax is executed properly.

Comment: @Sandeep.sarkar: Good idea. And yes, the script in 'formprocessing.php' seems correct. That is, if I type "xxx" into the input field, the script generated is:
 <script> {"content":"xxx"} </script>.
Which seems correct (I've removed the alert). On the other hand, the content does not seem to arrive back at form.php, i.e. the content is not being attached to the div element. I'll be experimenting further with Firebug.
   </script>

Comment: Don't use IE console please, do a favor to yourself and download Firebug for Firefox, it's really useful

Comment: I don't get why you need to load jquery and html tags in formprocessing.php, it's unnecessary as far as I see. Do a console.log(data) on the post done function to see what you're getting from the formprocessing.php.

Comment: Try removing other echo from formprocessing.php leaving only your json_encode() line. In ajax response, you might get the echo value, but its considered as malformed json response. Hence the $.post() will not consider it as a success and wont execute anything inside success function. `$.post('url',{data},function(response){},'json').fail(function(response){})` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your formprocessing.php file only needs:

```
<?php
   $invoer = isset($_POST['s']) ? $_POST['s'] : 'not set';
   echo '$invoer is:'.$invoer; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying this, `#result` for me gets filled with the following data:

`{"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"length":9},"selector":"#content"}`

Probably not entirely what you're looking for. Aside from that the event gets triggered, but you're making a few fatal mistakes:

1. There is element with id #content what formprocessing.php creates.
2. alert() will never be executed with ajax. With ajax, you are just loading the data statically. The script element is there, but it's not supposed be actually executed
3. You probably just want to emit real json from formprocessing.php. To do this, get rid of all the html, make sure you emit a `application/json` content type and *only* return json.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on your point 3. Getting rid of the HTML leaves me with just this:

<?php
 $invoer = $_POST['s'];
 echo ( json_encode(array("content" => $invoer)) );  
?>
 which jQuery does not accept.
Also, I'm not sure how to "emit a application/json content type and only return json".