# Why is isset($_POST['submit1']) equal to FALSE?

Tags: php, post, isset

This is a follow-up of another question that I posted a few hours ago ([PHP post method apparently not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325764/php-post-method-apparently-not-working)).
The code still does not do what it should, but the code and also the question itself have changed so much that I prefer to post a new question (also considering that questions seem to be read mainly immediately after they have been posted). I’ll try to close the earlier question (still somewhat new here).

On to the question then: why is, in the code given below, isset($_POST['submit1']) equal to FALSE when tested? In other words, why is  $_POST['submit1'] equal to NULL? 
I believe that’s all I need to know.

Here is the code, which consists of two files. The file ‘form.php’ (copied almost literally from the jQuery-site:  http://www.visualjquery.net/category/Ajax/jQuery.post , see last example) contains the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery.post demo</title>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="formprocessing.php" name="formpje" id="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit1" />
</form>

<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault();

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $( this ),
term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
url = $form.attr( 'action' );

/* Send the data using post */
var posting = $.post(url,{s: term},'json');

/* Put the results in a div */
posting.done(function( data ) {
var content1 = $( data ).find( '#content' );
contentstring = JSON.stringify(content1);
$( "#result" ).empty().append( contentstring );

});


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file ‘formprocessing.php’ contains the following (this includes the isset-test):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
echo ( json_encode(array("content" => $invoer)) ); 
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `isset($_POST['s'])`?

Comment: In your `$.post` code you don't send the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never set `submit1` as part of your data object that you're passing to `$.post()`:

```
var posting = $.post(url,{s: term},'json');
```

`$.post()` does not automatically pass through all of your form values; it only sends what you specify in its second argument. The only thing that will be set in `$_POST` is the `'s'` key.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're only posting data for `s`; there's no `submit1` in your submitted data object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

```
if(isset($_POST['s'])) {
     echo ( json_encode(array("content" => $invoer)) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data from your textbox is being sent (name="s"), not your name="submit1" guy. So either include 'submit1' in your post or look for the 's' value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to serialize the form. So you will get all the element including submit1 from your form.